# I am trying to check the first digit of my record_array of text type starts with 4 to 9 in postgres

Tags: postgresql

In a Postgres procedure, I have a regexp_split_to_array and storing it into an array of text type (named `_array`) .

in _array[1] --> i am setting this value to a variable number.

I want to check if the number starts with digits 4 to 9 before i set the value.

I tried with

```
IF _array[1] IS NOT NULL
THEN
_array[1].indexof(0).equals ('4' to '9')

RAISE EXCEPTION 'NUMBER starts from 4 to 9'
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for

```
substr(_array[1], 1, 1) BETWEEN '4' AND '9'
```

Comment: but substring will give me the extracted part...i want a boolean response

Comment: The (complete) expression in my answer will produce a `boolean`.